# Документация по наведению мыши

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Изучаю Spring на IDE IntelJIdea.
Хочу почитать что делает тот или иной метод, аннотация.
Я знаю что есть хоткей показывающий документацию, но он работает только
для базового java. А когда смотришь на метод из Spring то там ничего толком нет.
Как решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если используете мавен, то в его панели выбираете все библиотеки и по правой кнопке можно запросить выкачать документацию.

Comment: спасибо помогло

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, помогло. На файл pom.xml нажать правой кнопкой в дереве проекта и там выбрать скачать документацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]